# Ability to monitor filter beacon data in wireshark using MAC address

Tags: wireshark, ibeacon

What would be the filter command in wireshark to find the specific MAC address of the beacon ?
So for the MAC address of F4:8B:F9:B0:61 how would I filter out this specific beacon in wireshark?

Error after following tutorial by davidyoung :
"Error in column 'payload protocol' dissector not found"

Comment: Can wireshark even work with Bluetooth LE?  I thought it to only worked with Ethernet and WiFi.

Comment: Looks like this is available with a plugin here: https://lacklustre.net/bluetooth/wireshark.html, but it requires dedicated custom hardware here to capture Bluetooth LE traffic: http://ubertooth.sourceforge.net/usage/start/

Comment: I completed the above tutorial @davidgyoung however, I get the error posted above.

Comment: davidgyoung: What is the best other method to sniff the ble packet ?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use Wireshark with Ubertooth, you must either build or buy the Ubertooth board:  http://ubertooth.sourceforge.net/

I have not done this, so I can not speak to the exact steps or the relative merits of this approach.  The approach I have taken to sniffing Bluetooth LE traffic is to buy a TI CC2540 USB dongle, which you can get with sniffing software for Windows:  http://processors.wiki.ti.com/index.php/BLE_sniffer_guide

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to the Ubertooth that @davidgyoung mentioned is the [Adafruit Bluefruit LE Sniffer](https://www.adafruit.com/products/2269). At $30 it is significantly cheaper than the Ubertooth.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you already have a hcidump or know how to create one.

try following as filter:

```
frame[7:6] == F4:8B:F9:B0:61
```

In Version 1.10.6 it seems to give me only the packages from that specific beacon.

It's possible to even create a dissector for the advertising data, if you know how to decode it.